# Laravel 5.4 querystring values containing +

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel instance that is receiving user & email signups through a querystring.

My test user is using the google feature where you can alias your emails to inboxes with a + symbol, eg.

test+account@gmail.com

When I parse the querystring, the plus has been removed and replaced with a space. Is there any way that I can avoid this happening? Is there a better way to configure my instance or to parse the content.

I have followed the recommendations given here but it seems to be being processed at a higher level in the stack.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Comment: For legacy reasons, it's not using the built-in authentication handler. Please don't recommend this as a solution to this problem.

Comment: This is actually normal behavior. The service or application that sends you these query strings should URL encode them.